# Remove all the subsets in a list of sets

Tags: clojure, set, subset

I have a list of set elements.  Example:

```
'([0 1 2][1 2 3] [4 5 6] [5 6 7] [0 1 2 3] [4 5 6 7])
```

I want to remove the subsets -- `[0 1 2] [1 2 3] [4 5 6] [5 6 7]` -- and the final answer should be `'([0 1 2 3] [4 5 6 7])`.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: (defn toset [vect] (into #{} vect)) 
(not(empty?(remove false?(map #(clojure.set/subset? (toset [0 1 2]) %1)(into [] (map #(toset %1) '([0 1 2 4])))))))                             This returns true or false based on if the list is a subset.

Comment: Note that there is a set type which looks like #{0 1 2}

Comment: Re-reading this question, I realize it is stated in confusing fashion. Lists, sets, and subsets are described, but lists and vectors are shown.

Answer (score 6):

```
(defn to-superset [ coll ]
  (loop [result () coll coll]
    (if (empty? coll) result
      (let  [x  (first coll)
             xs (rest coll)]
            (if (some #(clojure.set/subset? x %) xs) 
                (recur result xs)
                (recur (cons x result) xs))))))

(to-superset '(#{0 1 2} #{1 2 3} #{4 5 6} #{5 6 7} #{0 1 2 3} #{4 5 6 7}))
```

**DEMO**

```
user=> (to-superset '(#{0 1 2} #{1 2 3} #{4 5 6} #{5 6 7} #{0 1 2 3} #{4 5 6 7}))
(#{4 5 6 7} #{0 1 2 3})
```

Comment: As far as I can tell, this is the only correct answer - the other answers seem to expect the subsets to be manually identified.

Comment: @Adrian Mouat , I think so too.

Comment: NOTE: My answer is with the assumption that order by the smaller number of elements.

Answer (score 2):

```
(def set1 '([0 1 2][1 2 3] [4 5 6] [5 6 7] [0 1 2 3] [4 5 6 7]))

(def set2 '([0 1 2] [1 2 3] [4 5 6] [5 6 7]))

(remove (set set2) set1)
```

Results :

```
([0 1 2 3] [4 5 6 7])
```

Comment: Note that it is more idiomatic to write literal sequences with vectors instead of quoted lists.  Also in this case, you could just use the set literal `#{[0 1 2] ...}`

Comment: I don't think this answers the question, you shouldn't need to specify set2

Comment: @AdrianMouat : he can make the second set, and remove it!

Comment: @Kugathasan You've not explained how to make the second set though. Note that it should be automatically created by identifying elements that are a subset of other elements.

Comment: @AdrianMouat : Did he provide the logic to get the subset..? He post the second set, not post the logic. Check the question.

Comment: @Kugathasan durai says "such as". I think durai is providing an example here, not exact input. I agree it isn't entirely clear, but I'm pretty sure BLUEPIXYs answer is the right one.

Comment: Yeah Bluepixys answer was correct.. And thanks for everyone else who had tried to help me.

Answer (score 1):

It should be as simple as (If you are not concerned about ordering)

```
(def a '( [1 2] [3 4] [5 6] ))
(def b '( [1 2] [33 34] [5 6] ))
(list* (set (conc­at a b)))
```

Comment: Sorry this is not the answer i was looking for.. May be i did not put the question correctly.. Thanks for your help.. I really appreciate your effort.

Comment: Yeah, I got what you meant exactly, anyway I hope you have got the required answer :)

Answer (score -1):

```
(apply list
       (difference
        (into #{}
              '([0 1 2] [1 2 3] [4 5 6] [5 6 7] [0 1 2 3] [4 5 6 7]))
        (into #{}
              '([0 1 2] [1 2 3] [4 5 6] [5 6 7]))))
```

Comment: `(apply list ..)` can be written as `(list* ..)`.